# Passing long configuration file to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I like the work methology of Kuberenetes, use self-contained image and pass the configuration in a ConfigMap, as a volume.

Now this worked great until I tried to do this thing with Liquibase container, The SQL is very long ~1.5K lines, and Kubernetes rejects it as too long.

Error from Kubernetes:

> The ConfigMap "liquibase-test-content" is invalid: metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 characters

I thought of passing the `.sql` files as a `hostPath`, but as I understand these `hostPath`'s content is probably not going to be there

Is there any other way to pass configuration from the K8s directory to pods? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [use an init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/#what-can-init-containers-be-used-for) for this. Essentially, put the `.sql` files on GitHub or S3 or really any location you can read from and populate a directory with it. The semantics of the init container guarantee that the Liquibase container will only be launched after the config files have been downloaded.

Answer (score 27):

The error you are seeing is not about the size of the actual ConfigMap contents, but about the size of the `last-applied-configuration` annotation that `kubectl apply` automatically [creates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/#how-to-create-objects) on each `apply`. If you use `kubectl create -f foo.yaml` instead of `kubectl apply -f foo.yaml`, it should work.

Please note that in doing this you will lose the ability to use `kubectl diff` and do incremental updates (without replacing the whole object) with `kubectl apply`.

Comment: it requires "k create" for the first install... and "k replace" for the subsequent upgrades... No more "k apply" for this case

Answer (score 22):

Since 1.18 you can use server-side apply to circumvent the problem.

`kubectl apply --server-side=true -f foo.yml`

where `server-side=true` runs the apply command on the server instead of the client.

This will properly show conflicts with other actors, including client-side apply and thus fail:

```bash
Apply failed with 4 conflicts: conflicts with "kubectl-client-side-apply" using apiextensions.k8s.io/v1:
- .status.conditions
- .status.storedVersions
- .status.acceptedNames.kind
- .status.acceptedNames.plural
Please review the fields above--they currently have other managers. Here
are the ways you can resolve this warning:
* If you intend to manage all of these fields, please re-run the apply
  command with the `--force-conflicts` flag.
* If you do not intend to manage all of the fields, please edit your
  manifest to remove references to the fields that should keep their
  current managers.
* You may co-own fields by updating your manifest to match the existing
  value; in this case, you'll become the manager if the other manager(s)
  stop managing the field (remove it from their configuration).
See http://k8s.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#conflicts
```

If the changes are intended you can simple use the first option:

`kubectl apply --server-side=true --force-conflicts -f foo.yml`

Comment: Does having two "apply" has any significance or is it a typo? I ran with single apply and it worked.!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a secret and b64enc.

They don't have the last-applied-configuration annotation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).